# Related Rates Word Problem (Boat+Rope)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

A rope is attached to a boat at water level, and a person on the dock is pulling on the rope at a rate of $50 \text{ ft/min}$. If the person's hands are $16 \text{ ft}$ above the water level, how fast is the boat approaching when the amount of rope out is $20 \text{ ft}$?

Here is what I did:
hypotenuse $= 20 \text{ ft} = C$

height of person above dock $= 16 \text{ ft} = A$

distance from dock to boat $= \sqrt{20^2-16^2} = \sqrt{12^2} = 12 = B$

$$A^2+B^2=C^2$$

$$A(dA/dt)+B(dB/dt) = C(dC/dt)$$

$$B(dB/dt) = C(dC/dt)$$

$$12(dB/dt)= 20(50)$$

$$dB/dt = 83.3 \text{ ft/min}$$

I am unsure about this answer because it seems like the boat is coming in too fast.

Comment: If the person can pull a total of $4$ feet of rope then the boat reaches the dock having travelled $12$ feet, so it is reasonable for for your answer to have the boat travelling faster than the rope.